# Evaluate sec 10 to the nearest hundreth

Tags: trigonometry

The question asks to evaluate sec 10 to the nearest hundredth.
My attempt:

$$\sec 10$$
$$=\frac 1{cos} 10$$
$$=\frac {10}{cos}$$
$$\approx 10.2$$

The text says the answer should be 1.02, but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: $$\sec 10=\frac{1}{\cos 10}$$but$$\frac{1}{\cos 10}\neq\frac{1}{\cos}10$$. In fact, $\cos$ doesn't make any sense - there's no value to evaluate there.

Comment: Just wondering though, how can $\frac{10}{cos}$ be equal to 10.2 ?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure where I went wrong.

Comment: @imranfat, just a guess, but typing "10 ÷ cos =" in  some calculators will be evaluated as 10÷cos(10), which rounds to 10.2.

Comment: @Paul.Gee, never thought about that...

Comment: $\cos(10)\approx -0.839$ so the set-up and the answer contradict each other.

Comment: @AS, you're doing it in radians, which is possible but unlikely here.

Comment: Take help of taylor series for sin and then convert it into cos using identity $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$ . $x$ is the angle which is 10 here.

Answer (score 1):

Working in radians (what I recommand you to use), you want to evaluate $$A=\sec (10 {}^{\circ})=\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)=\frac 1 {\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)}$$ Now, remember that, for small angles, by Taylor $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ So, $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\approx 1-\frac{\pi ^2}{648}$$ which means that $$A=\sec \left(\frac{\pi }{18}\right)\approx \frac 1{1-\frac{\pi ^2}{648}}$$ But again, when $x$ is small $$\frac 1 {1-x}\approx 1+x$$ So, $$A\approx 1+\frac{\pi ^2}{648}\approx 1.01523$$ while the exact value would be $\approx 1.01543$.